# Using Knockout JS in an all-eyecandy scenario?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, knockout.js

I am looking into KnockoutJS, and it looks really awesome, but I am not too fond of the way [animations](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html) have to be implemented.

So, my question is, in a very animation-intensive application, should I use knockout? Is there a preferred, organized way of handling animations?

The way I see it, it's either DOM-hell or a slight mix of both. I read [this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/integrating-knockoutjs-third-party-libraries), and a few pieces of code, mainly the next one, already looks like a slight mess to me:

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: queuedPhotos">
    <li data-bind="attr: { 'data-id' : queuedPhotoId }, click: select, css: { selected: $root.selectedPhoto() !== undefined && $root.selectedPhoto().queuedPhotoId() === queuedPhotoId() }">
        <img src="img/cross.png" alt="Remove" title="Remove" class="remove" data-bind="click: remove" />
        <img data-bind="attr: { 'src' : smallImageUrl, 'alt' : title, title: title }" />
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Personally, I would use Knockout and figure out the rest :)  Using KnockoutJS for me has made a huge, positive impact on the maintainability of the application logic.  That said, I'd definitely want to take the animations that you require, and abstract them into a custom Knockout plugin or per-item custom binding.  I wouldn't want to write css like that on a bunch of elements.

Comment: I'm surprised people didn't find this question more interesting. I think it's a very relevant subject.

Answer (score 3):

Knockout is an excellent library for binding data and manipulating the dom. As far as the binding syntax hell that you mention, will eventually creep up if you have a lot of functionality handed to an element. Even simple things like a visible binding could see use of over 4 or 5 values to show or hide. This said, the typical approach is to create a custom binding handler to clean up that or use unobtrusive binding, something which Ryan Niemeyer talks about in his blog http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html

There are various techniques (and knockmeout.net is an excellent resource, check out some of the videos from his presentation about unobtrusive bindings).

All in all, animations is not something Knockout does inherently. It leaves the implementation to the developer. Whether use jQuery to do it, d3.js or Raphael to manage canvas animations or the thousands thats already out there is totally up to you.

Keep your viewmodels simple (complex logic is not what I mean, simple means, it has a specific function and is not doing a zillion things in 1), keep your views simple and move the heavy lifting to a custom Binding handler or some other library.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ive thought of this, and another question came to mind: jquery plugins/controls will need custom bindings, right?

Comment: Yes, jquery widgets should be custom bindings, check my collection of bindings https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

Comment: yes, jquery plugins can have custom bindings. You are not forced to it though. You could still write jquery code in your viewmodel, but then, your viewmodel is now aware of your view elements, which kinda deviates from the whole idea of viewmodels having no clue of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use computed observables, you should only use the data-bind attribute for metadata, like

```
data-bind="enable: canSave"
```

not

```
data-bind="enable: errors().length == 0"
```

There are also libraries that remove or minimize the use of data-bind attributes, I have made one that uses Convention over configuration check it out here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

With my lib this line of code

```
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave"></button>
```

Would be

```
<button data-name="save"></button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ajnj/